# googledrive R library 404 not found

Tags: r

I am using `R 3.6.3` on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and `googledrive` version 1.0.1

I am downloading data from this open google drive folder with about 3k files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-owdnU_9_lpei1wbTBpS3RyTW8?resourcekey=0-SxZAhXpvnVSBVJjG_HYZ_w

if you add it to a google account of yours you can see that:

```
library(googledrive)
drive_about()

s2012 <- drive_ls(path = "CSV Stazione_Parametro_AnnoMese", pattern = paste0("storico_2012"))
drive_download(file = as_id(s2012$id[1]))
```

Which returns:

```
Error: Client error: (404) Not Found
  *       domain: global
  *       reason: notFound
  *      message: File not found: 0B-owdnU_9_lpY0otY3FYaF9nOG8.
  * locationType: parameter
  *     location: fileId
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_error()
<error/gargle_error_request_failed>
Client error: (404) Not Found
  *      message: File not found: 0B-owdnU_9_lpSGR2SGtCUnlRekk.
  *       domain: global
  *       reason: notFound
  *     location: fileId
  * locationType: parameter
Backtrace:
  1. base::mapply(function(x) drive_download(file = as_id(x)), bla$id)
  3. googledrive::drive_download(file = as_id(x))
  5. googledrive:::as_dribble.drive_id(file)
  6. googledrive::drive_get(id = x)
  8. purrr::map(as_id(id), get_one_file)
  9. googledrive:::.f(.x[[i]], ...)
 10. gargle::response_process(response)
 11. gargle:::stop_request_failed(error_message(resp), resp)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Note that the tibble of drive_ls is:

```
s2012
# A tibble: 201 x 3
   name                          id                           drive_resource   
 * <chr>                         <chr>                        <list>           
 1 storico_2012_07000027_005.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpY0otY3FYaF9nOG8 <named list [37]>
 2 storico_2012_10000001_005.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpcmFkUDYwUzh4X0k <named list [37]>
 3 storico_2012_05000020_010.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpcTlEMTFpbjJLSVE <named list [37]>
 4 storico_2012_03000006_005.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpbDJiNFZWUy1CcEU <named list [37]>
 5 storico_2012_09000018_111.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpRHlwN0JnNVNseDg <named list [37]>
 6 storico_2012_07000041_005.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpV1hINnZtSFRYaTg <named list [37]>
 7 storico_2012_04000155_009.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpMzh6a29BQ3hJbHM <named list [37]>
 8 storico_2012_09000014_020.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpS0Y0ZFIzbV9mX1U <named list [37]>
 9 storico_2012_03000006_038.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpMlpGbkpFdVdURzQ <named list [37]>
10 storico_2012_06000036_009.csv 0B-owdnU_9_lpa0kxTTBuLU83U2s <named list [37]>
# … with 191 more rows
```

Note that it perfectly works for other files in the same folder.

Any hint?

A question aside: is there any alternative to this library? `googledrive`struggles to find all files available based a specific pattern, i.e. it has be run multiple times to find them all.

Thx,

A